# Why I a getting the error xpected XmlNodeType.Element, type is Whitespace?

Tags: c#

What is wrong in this program

```
var modifiedXML = @" <system.webServer><rewrite><rules><rule name='rule 1D' stopProcessing='false'><match url='^(.*)$'/><!--<action type= 'Rewrite' url='//offline.html'/>--></rule></rules></rewrite></system.webServer>";
            var configuration = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");           
            var section = configuration.GetSection("system.webServer");
            section.SectionInformation.SetRawXml(modifiedXML);
            configuration.Save();
```

**Error:**

> An exception of type
>   'System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException' occurred in
>   System.Configuration.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: expected XmlNodeType.Element, type is
>   Whitespace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to change

```
var modifiedXML = @" <system.webServer>...
```

to

```
var modifiedXML = @"<system.webServer>...
```

(unnecessary space before the root element).